# net WCF client configure htts

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, webservice-client

I am trying to connect to a web service 'https://trackingqa.estafeta.com/Service.asmx' programaticaly what i mean is with code no configuration (.config)
I try this

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(url);
        ServiceSoapClient client = new ServiceSoapClient(binding, endpoint);
```

but i get this error:

> The client certificate is not provided. Specify a client certificate in ClientCredentials.

i found this doc on MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication#configure-the-client)

and i try this:

```
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My,
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "TrackingQA.estafeta.com");
```

but i getting this error:

> Exception: Cannot find X.509 certificate with the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'CurrentUser', FindType 'FindBySubjectName', FindValue 'TrackingQA.estafeta.com'.

my question is how configure de endpoint in the client

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.,
Works for me.

1. Set security protocol

   ```
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
   ```
2. set certificate

   ```
    client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(StringCertificateBase64));
   ```

complete code:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(url);
        ServiceSoapClient client= new ServiceSoapClient(binding, endpoint);
        client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(StringCertificateBase64));
```